# How to find the common root of a sequence of strings recursively?

Tags: string, scala, recursion, sequences

I want to be able to read in a sequence of strings and return the common stem of the strings. For example, if I had the following sequence:

```
val testSeq: Seq[String] = Seq("RootA_", "RootB_", "RootC_")
```

Then only the string "Root" should be returned.

My current function looks like this but using intersect means that the unwanted "`_`" is returned as part of the root, i.e. "Root_". I tried using takeWhile but was unsuccessful.

```
def findRoot(ss: Seq[String], root: String): String = ss match {
  case h :: Nil => h.intersect(root)
  case h :: t => findRoot(t, h.intersect(t.head))
}
```

If there's a built in Scala method for this could you please let me know! Otherwise if anyone wants to have a crack at solving this one it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no scala stdlib function returning common prefix of two strings.

You can calculate common prefix using `zip` and `takeWhile`

```
def findRoot(seq: Seq[String]): String = {                               

    def prefix(a: String, b: String) = a                         
        .zip(b)                        
        .takeWhile { case (a, b) => a == b }
        .map(_._1) 
        .mkString                                                

    @tailrec                                                     
    def find(ss: Seq[String], root: String): String = ss match { 
        case h :: Nil => prefix(h, root)                         
        case h :: t => find(t, prefix(h, root))                  
    }                                                            

    find(seq.tail, seq.head)                                     

}
```